# Multiple forms in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a webpage with a form, which looks kinda like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // html input fields here
    // ...
    // [SUBMIT]
}
```

When a user presses on the submit button, then the following function is called:

```
public ActionResult MyAction ( string id )
{
    // default action
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction ( MyModel model )
{
    // called when a form is submitted
}
```

Now my problem is, is that i have to add another form. But how can i tell which form was submitted? Because both will now end up in the second (HttpPost) method...

What would be a good way to separate both form actions? Please note that when a form is submitted, that i must stay on the same page. I can't redirect myself to another page/controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you will have a page with two forms in it.
As a first approach I will post each form to a different action of the same controller.

The first

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
```

The second

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction2", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
```

and then, a little refactoring on your two actions to follow the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

If instead you need both form to post to the same action, then I will put a hidden input to let me know wich one was called.

Comment: I thought about that too, but then both actions will have the same code, like getting data from the database. You're talking about DRY, does that mean it's perfectly okay to create a private method in my controller, which both Actions can use?

Comment: Yes why not?. You refactor your code in a function that will be called from many places. You can also think of creating an extension method, but I don't really know what you do in your code.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple forms on one page/view and would like to post to different actions add the name html attribute to the beginform method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action1", "contollerName", new { @name = "form1" }))
{
    ...add view code
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("action2", "contollerName", new { @name = "form2" }))
{
    ...add view code
}
```

Having a different name for each form will allow MVC to easily determine which action to post to rather than relying on different form collection values to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the data without redirecting I would suggest you to use JQuery Ajax for that. you can use the following as a sample

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#IdOfButton').click(function(){ 

      $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/MyAction',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
           PropertyInModel : ValueFromView
           //for values you need to pass from view to controller
        },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });

    });
});
```

your action would look like this

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction ( MyModel model )
    {
        // called when a form is submitted
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

Comment: What do you do when you need to return the errors on the model? Such as if(ModelState.IsValid) evaluates to false and you want to simply return the model back to the view and have the ValidationSummary display the model errors.